# Trackable links to my app in the App Store

Tags: ios, itunes

I have an iPhone application which I would like to promote across a few websites and of course I would like track the number of installations received from leads who came from these wesites. I'm wondering whether it is possible
to have a different iTunes links  which I will share with the different websites, and then, somehow track these stats
or be able to track different sources by HTTP referrer 
or maybe be able to pass any valuable (in sense of referred source) somewhere in itunes url and then read it
any other approach

of course I need to collect this information on every successful installation.

Can you please advise me an approach to deal with such facilities?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you go: ["Automatically Track App Sale Referrals" (Blog entry on atastypixel.com)](http://atastypixel.com/blog/automatically-track-app-sale-referrals/)

It's basically this: Use your own webserver to create custom download links which redirect to the App Store, and use a statistics tool of your choice to look at the log files (or use an external service like [LinkShare](http://www.linkshare.com) which does that part for you).

Apple, unfortunately, does not provide detailed statistics (with referrers etc.) via iTunes Connect, so doing it yourself is the way to go.

Comment: Thank you. Do I understand it correct that this guys (LinkShare) have some exclusive partnership with Apple and thus can retrieve installation data, while it will never be accessible for the rest?

Comment: @Eugene: Yes, they do seem to have an exclusive partnership with Apple. Details: http://www.apple.com/itunes/affiliates/faq.html  However, if you have the option to provide individual links to different referrers, you can add up the number of redirects without LinkShare.

Comment: >> However, if you have the option to provide individual links to different referrers, you can add up the number of redirects without LinkShare
Yes, I have such option. But how I will track the sources then (in other words how can I trace an individual link into specific installation)?

Comment: @Eugene You mean you have your own webserver where you can create the redirects? If so, this webserver should have a regular log, which you can examine. You'd just create redirects like yourwebsite.com/yourapp/affiliate1, yourwebsite.com/yourapp/affiliate2 etc., and count the requests for this individual url that you give to affiliate 1 or affiliate 2 respectively. You could also look at the "referrer" HTTP header of the incoming request: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_referer

Comment: of course I understand that, but I'm interested about installation statistics only, clicks is not enough at all

Comment: I mean that I'm Ok to use referers, but is there a way to read this referer in a some way on installation without building some server-side tracking software (so e.g. without placement of the cookie during the redirection trail and then reading it from the application)?

Comment: @Eugene: Not as far as I know.

Comment: @AndreasLey I am not able to understand how is it verified whether the user did actually install the app post clicking the link. What I understand is that if we don't use LinkShare, and just want to track whether a user installed the app via a link or directly through the app store (by searching for it), it is not possible. Right?

Comment: @AkshatSinghal Unfortunately, there is no way to track installations. This answer is only about tracking referrer links to the app store.