# Identify the source of the iOS app installation

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, app-store, app-store-connect

I have developed iPhone app, it is available on the store.

Now for promoting my app i have have used various websites, now my problem is, i want to identify from which website my app got downloaded?

Is there any way in which i can identify how user reached to my app in the AppStore? from which source?

Comment: You want the link to your app page ?

Comment: yes something similar to this only, how user reached to my app ?

Comment: I dint get...Be specific ..what you want ?

Comment: suppose user is right now in `Yahoo.com` and on the side he see my app advertisement, when he clicks on that he will redirected to the my app in iTunes. so this i want to identify that user actually came from `Yahoo.com`.

Comment: Have a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13015165/trackable-links-to-my-app-in-the-app-store

Answer (score 0):

To do this you need some site/webpage to save statistic (there are lot of web services like google-analytics), and redirect to app store, on all promotion share link to this site.